# How can I write a code that will return the answers from a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I've made two seperate dictionaries, `rdict(recipes)`, which contain the recipes, and `totalcal(data)` which contain the calories for each ingredient. I learnt that using dictionaries in this task would be helpful so, with the help of many kind StackOverflow users, I have formulated my code like this...

```
def rdict(recipes):
    d = dict()
    for r in recipes:
        i = dict()
        r_ = r.split(':')
        for c_ in r_[1].split(','):
            i_ = c_.split('*')
            i[i_[0].strip()] = int(i_[1])
        d[r_[0]] = i
    return d
def totalcal(data):
    calorie_dict = {}
    for el in data:
      food, values = el.split(':')
      a, b, c = values.split(',')
      calories = (int(a) * 5) + (int(b) * 5) + (int(c) * 9)
      calorie_dict[food] = calories
    return calorie_dict
```

So, now I want to create a new function `gathercal(recipes, data)` which will return the total calories consumed.

For instance, in `gathercal(recipes, data)` if

```
recipes = [[
    "Pork Stew:Cabbage*5,Carrot*1,Fatty Pork*10",
    "Green Salad1:Cabbage*10,Carrot*2,Pineapple*5",
    "T-Bone:Carrot*2,Steak Meat*1"
]]
```

and

```
data = [
   'Cabbage': 30, 
   'Carrot': 95, 
   'Fatty Pork': 2205, 
   'Pineapple': 40, 
   'Steak Meat': 215, 
   'Rabbit Meat': 225
]
```

The output would have to go through this

```
[
   "Pork Stew" : {(30 * 5)+(95 * 1)+(2205 * 10) = 22,295}, 
   "Green Salad1" : {(30 * 10)+(95 * 2)+(40 * 5) = 690}, 
   "T-bone" : {(95 * 2)+(215 * 1) = 405}
]
```

So the output should return this as a **dictionary**...

```
["Pork Stew":{22,295}, "Green Salad1": {690}, "T-bone" : {405}]
```

I honestly have no clue on how to do this... I have all the necessary data and I created helper functions to get the data, but I can't seem to get this part.

**What is the simplest way to write this code without using import, collections.iter or like lamda??**

Comment: you will have to parse all data, keep names with values as dictionary to replace it and calculate it. I think it can't be simple.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables.

Comment: you can't use ` a, b, c = ...` because some recipes have less elements. You should get it as list and use `for`-loop to calculate.

Comment: @furas yea I tried to do it but it didn't work.. I dunno if I'm doing it wrong or smth

Comment: first `for`-loop seems OK - I made similar but with names which means something so it is simpler to read code.

Comment: yea like independently I can do it for each of them but to find ways to integrate it together is a bit of a challenge for me ngl

Comment: Split each recipe on a colon to get the name and ingredients.  Then split the ingredients on a comma to get each ingredient.  Then split each ingredient on an asterisk to get the ingredient name and amount.

Comment: Thank u for ur explaination but I'm afraid I can't follow what ur tryna say, can u express it as a code pls?

Answer (score 1):

My version:

Spliting recipes is similar to your version but I use names which means something - so it is simpler to read code.

I assumed that `data` doesn't need splitings.

```
recipes = [
    "Pork Stew:Cabbage*5,Carrot*1,Fatty Pork*10",
    "Green Salad1:Cabbage*10,Carrot*2,Pineapple*5",
    "T-Bone:Carrot*2,Steak Meat*1"
]

data = {
   'Cabbage': 30, 
   'Carrot': 95, 
   'Fatty Pork': 2205, 
   'Pineapple': 40, 
   'Steak Meat': 215, 
   'Rabbit Meat': 225
}

# --- split recipes ---

recipes_splitted = {}

for r in recipes:

    recipe_name, parts = r.split(":")
    recipe_parts = {}

    for part in parts.split(','):
        product, number = part.split('*')
        recipe_parts[product] = int(number)

    recipes_splitted[recipe_name] = recipe_parts
    
# --- display recipes_splitted ---

print('\n--- recipes_splitted ---\n')        
#for recipe_name, recipe_parts in recipes_splitted.items():    
for recipe_name in recipes_splitted:    
    recipe_parts = recipes_splitted[recipe_name]
    print(recipe_name, recipe_parts)

# --- calculate calories ---

print('\n--- calculate calories ---\n')

recipes_calories = {}   
    
#for recipe_name, recipe_parts in recipes_splitted.items():
for recipe_name in recipes_splitted:
    recipe_parts = recipes_splitted[recipe_name]

    print('---', recipe_name, '---')
    calories = 0

    #for product, number in recipe_parts.items():
    for product in recipe_parts:
        number = recipe_parts[product]
        print(product, ':', number)
        calories += number * data[product]

    print('>>> calories =', calories)
    recipes_calories[recipe_name] = calories
    
print()    
print(recipes_calories)

# --- display recipes_calories---

print('\n--- recipes_calories ---\n')        

#for recipe_name, calories in recipes_calories.items():    
for recipe_name in recipes_calories:    
    calories = recipes_calories[recipe_name]    
    print(recipe_name, ":", calories)
```

Result:

```
--- recipes_splitted ---

Pork Stew {'Cabbage': 5, 'Carrot': 1, 'Fatty Pork': 10}
Green Salad1 {'Cabbage': 10, 'Carrot': 2, 'Pineapple': 5}
T-Bone {'Carrot': 2, 'Steak Meat': 1}

--- calculate calories ---

--- Pork Stew ---
Cabbage : 5
Carrot : 1
Fatty Pork : 10
>>> calories = 22295
--- Green Salad1 ---
Cabbage : 10
Carrot : 2
Pineapple : 5
>>> calories = 690
--- T-Bone ---
Carrot : 2
Steak Meat : 1
>>> calories = 405

{'Pork Stew': 22295, 'Green Salad1': 690, 'T-Bone': 405}

--- recipes_calories ---

Pork Stew : 22295
Green Salad1 : 690
T-Bone : 405
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without using .items?? Like I haven't learnt abt it yet and I dont wanna rush it

Comment: instead of `for product, number in recipe_parts.items():` you can do `for product in recipe_parts: number = recipe_parts[product]`

Comment: I changed code in answer - now is without `.items()` (but I keep `.items()` in comments)